# How to delay a function call inside a express controller without hanging the API?

Tags: node.js, express, delay

I'm learning to develop an ExpressJS API and I need to know how to delay the call of a function but to answer the client with a success code even if the process has not ended.

A simple code sample would be:

```
router.post('/', (req,res) => {
   if(req.body.success) {
      createRecord(req.body); // I need this function to be called after X minutes
   }
   return res.status(201).send(`Record will be created in X min from ${now}.`)
});
```

While searching I found the function setTimeout. However, is not clear to me how does it work.

- The client needs to wait X minutes to receive my success message?
- The function createRecord is called even if the function already returned an answer?
- The API will still available for other calls in the X minutes period of time?

I hope someone could help me to clarify my doubts. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you don't know `setTimeout` then you don't understand the event loop in JS. Here's a [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0) that you REALLY need to watch!

Meanwhile I'll briefly explain the basics.

You know that when you call a function, it'll exec each line of code in its body in time order, up till it hits a return, throws an error, or reaches the last line.

When one of the line is a call to `setTimeout(myDelayedFn, 1000)`, the call to setTimeout itself is executed in time order. It sends a request to the runtime, telling it to SCHEDULE a call to `myDelayedFn` AT LEAST 1000ms later.

> Not to confuse the term *request* I used here is NOT network request. You can think of it as a *signal*.

So setTimeout just *sends a request* for a scheduled work, but that work is not executed. Execution of `myDelayedFn` falls out of time order since it's SCHEDULED. It also means you normal line-by-line execution order is not interrupted (we say it doesn't BLOCK the execution). After sending the request, execution continues to next line in function body.

This means "no", "yes", "yes" to your 3 questions.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm still in the learning process. People like you helps a lot

Comment: @XylethAbsol no problem, welcome to stackoverflow :)

Comment: This does'nt answer the question asked

Comment: @ShubhDixit If you read OP's question REALLY carefully, you'll see. My humble answer without any code example is the only one really trying to help him. That's why he accepted mine.

Comment: @ShubhDixit OP doesn't need code, he needs explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a express middleware function for that

```
function delay(req, res, next) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("delay occurred"); // do the task you want to do
        if (true) {
            console.log("record created after 3 seconds"); // I need this function to be called after X minutes
        }
    }, 3000)
}

// you can return response here ,so that client doesn't have to wait
router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
    return res.status(201).send(`Record will be created in X min from ${now}.`)
    
    next(); // call next here
}, delay);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Step 1: Add a next to your function. It passes the context of your API call to another route handler. This enables you to pass the success message immediately and then do something else afterwards in your own time

 router.post('/', (req,res, next) => {
       if(req.body.success) {
       return res.status(201).send(`Record will be created in X min from ${now}.`);
    }
next(); // This sends the context of the original request to the next function underneath it.
    });

// Step 2: Function that promisifies the setTimeout function.
    const waitHere = (time) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time));
setTimeout is an async function so it will wait

Step 2 - Option 1:
    router.use('/', async (req,res, next) => {
       if(req.body.success) {
    await waitHere(1000 * 60 *2); // 2 minute wait
          createRecord(req.body); 
    });
OR

Step 2 Option 2:
No need for the async since you're not doing anything else in the second function handler 
 router.use('/', (req,res) => {
       if(req.body.success) {
    setTimeout(() => {
 createRecord(req.body); 
}, 1000 * 60 * 2);

    });
```

The API will still available for other calls in the X minutes period of time?
- yes, each execution of the API is unique.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Adrian, in the Option 1, the client has to wait the 2 minutes to receive the answer? Maybe I did not explain my requirment to weel. I need that the client receives the answer just by checking req.body.success , so he knows that after some time the record will be created, I don't want to him wait until the creation is complete. Hope this is more clear

Comment: Hey @XylethAbsol, so you need to copy both bits of my code, there are two middleware handlers, the bit at the top and then option 1 or option 2.

So the user will get the notification right away, but then the database record will be created 2 mins later

Answer (score 0):

You can use setTimeout function once you get response and it will delay x minutes.

```
router.post('/', (req,res) => {
    if(req.body.success) {
    setTimeout(100, function(){
            
    createRecord(req.body); // I need this function to be called after X minutes
    });
    return res.status(201).send(`Record will be created in X min from ${now}.`)
}
});
```